# Linear layout displays squares instead of circles for big sized dots (.)

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's a snippet of the code

```
static TextView mDotsText[];
private int mDotsCount;
private LinearLayout mDotsLayout;
    mDotsLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.image_count);
    mDotsCount = viewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
    mDotsText = new TextView[mDotsCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < mDotsCount; i++) {
                   mDotsText[i] = new TextView(this);
                   mDotsText[i].setText(".");
                   mDotsText[i].setTextSize(45);
                   mDotsText[i].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                   mDotsText[i].setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);
                   mDotsLayout.addView(mDotsText[i]);
                  }
```

In the setText I have used a dot (.) but when I increase the textsize to 45, it turns out to be  a square rather than circle which I was hoping it to be.  Here's a snippet my XML file.

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/image_count"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_pager"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:background="#00000000"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

How can I turn these squares to circles.  Maybe through padding or something else.  Please help?

Comment: In case of digital electronics every screen is made up of square pixels. You never notice it because they are too tiny. A simple example would be calculator or a hand help brick game. If you remember, the images or the text that they display were always displayed using squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
mDotsText[i].setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
```

instead of

```
mDotsText[i].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Good luck!